# Multinetwork: cannot activate test account (using faucet)

Tags: node, testnet, activate

I am running a [multinetwork node](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/multinetwork.html), with a mainnet node (P2P port 9732, RPC port 8732) and a delphinet node (P2P port 9733, RPC port 8733, config.json and data is in folder `~/tezos-delphinet/`). Nodes are syncing and everything is fine.

I wanted to test with some [free tez](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html?highlight=rpc%20addr#get-free-tez), so I went to the [Tezos Faucet](https://faucet.tzalpha.net/), dowloaded the JSON file and like the guide said I tried to activate the account (the guide should include the `base-dir`, `addr` and  `port` flags, I think!):

`tezos-client --base-dir ~/tezos-delphinet/ --addr 127.0.0.1 --port 8733 activate account wallet1 with ~/tezos-delphinet/tz1YDX6MLpHwziXQfKBmAMDcU6reBEyrfiyn.json`

The node is bootstrapped. The response is:

```
Waiting for the node to be bootstrapped before injection...
Current head: BLNMurhtj4c2 (timestamp: 2020-09-04T20:42:33-00:00, validation: 2020-09-04T20:42:34-00:00)
Current head: BLHvPjLmXPoa (timestamp: 2020-09-04T20:43:23-00:00, validation: 2020-09-04T20:43:24-00:00)
Current head: BLFL36V6rd19 (timestamp: 2020-09-04T20:44:21-00:00, validation: 2020-09-04T20:44:22-00:00)


^CSep  4 22:45:12 - client.main: Received the INT signal, triggering shutdown.
Fatal error:
  Lwt.Resolution_loop.Canceled
```

I terminated because it took too long.

```
tezos-client --base-dir ~/tezos-delphinet --addr 127.0.0.1 --port 8733 activate account wallet1 with ~/tezos-delphinet/tz1YDX6MLpHwziXQfKBmAMDcU6reBEyrfiyn.json
Error:
  The secret_key alias wallet1 already exists.
    The current value is unencrypted:edsk3CPr7____________.
    Use --force to update
```

But the balance is zero:

```
tezos-client --base-dir ~/tezos-delphinet --addr 127.0.0.1 --port 8733 get balance for wallet1
0 ꜩ
```

Answer (score 0):

Your node is NOT bootstrapped. If it was, you would NOT see those timestamp messages.

Comment: It is... that's one problem. In fact, when I tried again it said "The secret_key alias wallet1 already exists." so it injected the operation.

Comment: Update current head to BKwrnZd1Dkh2wEt8wQLtFq4oT9rVRnBtScCfscTfJQRKUmicAtf (level 480, timestamp 2020-09-04T21:40:35-00:00, fitness 01::00000000000001df)

Comment: tezos-client will not inject operations to a node that is not bootstrapped. If your node is indeed bootstrapped then tezos-client will NOT output the clear-as-day phrase "Waiting for the node to be bootstrapped".

Comment: I agree with you and assume that what I described is a bug.

Comment: The bug being that the account was created even though the operation was never injected?

Comment: @arvidj the bug is that even if the node was bootstrapped, the client thought that it was not. Other than that, it seems that the operation was injected (balance = 0, is it normal for a faucet account?).